# Batch file Change Directory

Tags: batch-file, directory

I've been wondering about changing the install location in a batch file game.
Best example of this question are DOS Games on how the setup/installer has this style:

::Install to: C:(Game name)

But you can change the location of where to install the game.
Please help if you can.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is, How can I make it so I can change the install Location of my batch file game (look at the example)?

Comment: That really doesn't help. What is the Batch file doing? What game are you trying to install? Is this a scripting question or a software installation question?

Comment: Like you know how those DOS games have their "Install to"(C:\(its game name), But I want to know how I can make that for my batch file BUT you can change where you want it to install to. Is that better? (I'm sorry, i'm a mentally challenged personnel =/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

`Echo Where do you want to install the game?
set /p install_dir=
copy` *"wherever your game is"*  `%install_dir%`

This will copy the game to wherever the user wants it installed

Comment: But I want it to be having a DEFAULT location:: Install to: "C:/DREALMS" and be able to edit it if they don't want to install the game there.

Comment: So you want a Default location, but the user can edit if he/she wants to?